# VS2017 working in windows 10 but not working in windows 8.1 ASPNET Core 2.0 HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure

Tags: visual-studio-2017, .net-core

VS2017 working in windows 10 but not working in windows 8.1
HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure

Common causes of this issue:
The application process failed to start
The application process started but then stopped
The application process started but failed to listen on the configured port

Troubleshooting steps:
Check the system event log for error messages
Enable logging the application process' stdout messages
Attach a debugger to the application process and inspect

For more information visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=808681

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default solution is to install KB2999226 of Microsoft

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2999226